Geometric interpretation of Lemma 1.5 from Kato-Kurokawa-Saito "Number Theory 1"
I recently started reading Kato-Kurokawa-Saito book "Number Theory 1", and while reading Lemma 1.5, estabilishing the following bijection

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic different from 2, and let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be distinct elements in $K$. Define $B$ and $C$ by
\begin{align}
  B &= \{(u, v, w) \in K \times K \times K\ |\ u^2 + a = v^2 + b = w^2 + c \}, \\
  C &= \{(x, y) \in K \times K\ |\ y^2 = (x - a)(x - b)(x - c),\ y \neq 0 \} \\
\end{align}
then there exist mutually inverse maps $f \colon B \to C$ and $g \colon C \to B$ given by
\begin{align}
  f(u, v, w) &= (u^2 + a + uv + vw + wu,\ (u + v)(v + w)(w + u)) \\
  g(x, y)    &= \left(\frac{(x - a)^2 - (b - a)(c - a)}{2y}, \frac{(x - b)^2 - (a - b)(a - c)}{2y}, \frac{(x - c)^2 - (a - c)(b - c)}{2y}\right) \\ 
\end{align}

I simply couldn't help myself from trying to extend the maps to their projective closures, that I assumed to be
\begin{align}
  \bar{B} &= Z(u^2 - v^2 = t^2(b - a),\ u^2 - w^2 = t^2(c - a),\ v^2 - w^2 = t^2(c - b)) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3(K) \\
  \bar{C} &= Z(zy^2 = (x - az)(x - bz)(x - cz)) \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2(K) \\
\end{align}
The additional points are:

$[a : 0 : 1]$, $[b : 0 : 1]$, $[c : 0 : 1]$ and $[0 : 1 : 0]$ in $\bar{C}$;
$[1 : 1 : 1 : 0]$, $[-1 : 1 : 1 : 0]$, $[1 : -1 : 1 : 0]$, and $[1 : 1 : -1 : 0]$ in $\bar{B}$.

At first I thought $f$ and $g$ would induce an isomorphism of algebraic varieties, but as soon I tried to extend them, I got a few problems both directions. I'll denote the extensions by $\bar{f} \colon \bar{B} \to \bar{C}$ and $\bar{g} \colon \bar{C} \to \bar{B}$.

Assuming $\bar{g}$ exists, we have to figure out where to map the remaining points. We know $g$ is its restriction on the intersection with the standard affine opens $\bar{C} \cap U_{z \neq 0} \cap U_{y \neq 0}$, and it maps any point $[x : y : 1]$, $y \neq 0$, to
\begin{align}
  \left[\, (x - a)^2 - (b - a)(c - a) : (x - b)^2 - (a - b)(a - c) : (x - c)^2 - (a - c)(b - c) : 2y\, \right]
\end{align}
This map still makes sense on $\bar{C} \cap U_{z \neq 0}$, so we may let $y = 0$ to get the images
\begin{align}
  \bar{f}([a : 0 : 1]) &= [-1 : 1 : 1 : 0] \\
  \bar{f}([b : 0 : 1]) &= [1 : -1 : 1 : 0] \\
  \bar{f}([c : 0 : 1]) &= [1 : 1 : -1 : 0] \\
\end{align}
However, so far I can't really think of any reasonable way to define $\bar{g}$ on $\bar{C} \cap U_{y \neq 0}$, in particular on $[0 : 1 : 0]$, expected to be mapped to $[1 : 1 : 1 : 0]$. My attempt was to guess an expression by first taking a point $[x : y : z] \in \bar{C} \cap U_{y \neq 0} \cap U_{z \neq 0}$ and getting inspired by its image, namely
\begin{align}
  \bar{g}([x : y : z])
    &= g(x/z, y/z) \\
    &= \left[\, (x/z - a)^2 - (b - a)(c - a) : (x/z - b)^2 - (a - b)(a - c) : (x/z - c)^2 - (a - c)(b - c) : 2y/z\, \right] \\
    &= \left[\, (x - az)^2 - z^2(b - a)(c - a) : (x - bz)^2 - z^2(a - b)(a - c) : (x - cz)^2 - z^2(a - c)(b - c) : 2yz\, \right]
\end{align}
where I multiplied everything by $z^2$ from the second to third row in order to remove $z$ from any denominator. The issue here is this expression is ill-defined for $x = z = 0$. I guess cases are two: there's no extension on $\bar{C} \cap U_{y \neq 0}$, or there's some clever way (I can't see) to use the elliptic curve equation to define the map on the chart in another way.

Similar situation for $\bar{f}$, where $f$ is its restriction on $\bar{B} \cap U_{t \neq 0}$, mapping any point $[u : v : w : t]$, $t \neq 0$, to
\begin{equation}
  \left[\, u^2t + at^2 + uvt + vwt + wut : (u + v)(u + w)(v + w) : t^3\, \right]
\end{equation}
However, for $t = 0$ the expression only makes sense for $[1 : 1 : 1 : 0]$ (which is of course mapped to $[0 : 1 : 0]$), but it's ill-defined for the other three points!


Question(s): Are $f$ and $g$ really extendable to $\bar{B}$ and $\bar{C}$? If the are, how? If they're not, why? What am I missing here?
